# Google chart timeline - render only some months

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, timeline

I made a google timeline chart that is connected to a google sheet with a sidebar user form. It works great. I put it in an iframe and render it on my website. However, my timeline is used for boat charter tours and they are active only in summer. I would like to know is it possible to render only months from May to October without the rest of the year.

[image: timeline]

As you can see there is empty space from October to May next year. I would like to erase that part of the timeline or scale it somehow so it does not take that much space. I'm willing to try all sorts of workarounds for this.

Comment: unfortunately, the Timeline chart will not accommodate. it is going to show all time within the min and max dates. my only suggestion would be to draw multiple charts, laid out side by side. then you could draw one chart for each year in the data...